# Why Media Creation Tools keep "redownloading windows" after failed upgrade?

Tags: windows-10

I use media creation tools to upgrade windows.

Upgrade fails for so many reasons. VMware installed and must be uninstalled. Sometimes unknown reasons.

I just try again. Every time I want to try again, it will "download" windows again.

Why should it be? It can't be checked that it has downloaded windows from before and the file is there?

Actually, where does the windows get downloaded anyway by media creation tools?

My SSD space in drive C is limited and I definitely want to save 8 GB of hard disk from that extra copy of windows.

Comment: *"My SSD space in drive C is limited and I definitely want to save 8 GB of hard disk from that extra copy of windows."* The tool automatically deletes the temp file after it creates your bootable media. Can you not just free up a few gigabytes of extra space using TreeSize to find some of your larger unused files? It sounds like your reluctance to free up sufficient space is the root cause behind many behind of these other problems.

Comment: How much free space is there on your C drive right now? It's hard to tell from your question if you're running out of space.

Comment: You need as much as 30 GB of free space to do a Repair Install or Feature upgrade to do the update and create Windows. old. So free up at least this much space and try again. This operation works for me.

Comment: "where does the windows get downloaded anyway by media creation tools?" - Microsoft servers if you want to avoid this step, download the ISO once, and then mount it within Windows 10.

Comment: it's downloaded on local hard disk I bet

Answer (score -1):

You need minimum 16GB - 32GB of space to install Windows. Create a bootable USB instead of upgrading it directly

Comment: I think we posted the very same thought above in comments and need the author to respond